# MVC 4 Styling @HTML Items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 4 `TextBoxFor` tags on a page. I want these tags to have the same css class. How do I do that?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

I have seen something like

`@Html.TextBoxFor("Name", m => m.Name, new {@class="contactUsTextBox"})`

and

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class="contactUsTextBox"})`

on other webpages, but those cause errors.

Comment: What errors does it cause?

Comment: `CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, string, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Is Name in your view model?

Comment: Looks like using the second example works now. Not sure what the issue was last time. Must have been a missing ',' or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be..

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class="contactUsTextBox"})
```

Make sure the **property** exists in the model, and also make sure the Css Class exists, the later won't cause an error, but you won't see any style.

Can you also post the `@model` at the top of the view, and the code for the actual `model`.

Also, explain the error you are seeing in the qustion.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@class="contactUsTextBox"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, 
                 new Dictionary<string, object> {{"class","contactUsTextBox"}})
```